# XML-Documentation of multiple exceptions for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception, xml-documentation

I'm actually searching for a guidline, how to document multiple exceptions in a public method inside a C#-DLL.

example:

```xml
/// <summary>
/// This method does something
/// </summary>
/// <param name="p_Parameter1">First parameter</param>
/// <param name="p_Parameter2">Second parameter</param>
/// <param name="p_Number">A number</param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
/// Thrown if p_Parameter1 is null</exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
/// Thrown if p_Parameter2 is null</exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
/// Thrown if any element of p_Parameter2 is null</exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
/// Thrown if p_Number is below or equal 0</exception>
/// <returns>A object</returns>
```

```cs
public static object DoSomething(
    object p_Parameter1, IList<object> p_Parameter2, 
    object p_Parameter3, int p_Number)
{
    if(p_Parameter1 == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(
            paramName:"p_Parameter1", 
            message:"Parameter is needed");
    if (p_Parameter2 == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(
            paramName: "p_Parameter2", 
            message: "Parameter is needed");

    for (int i = 0; i < p_Parameter2.Count; i++)
    {
        if(p_Parameter2[i] == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(
                paramName: String.Format("p_Parameter2[{0}]", i),
                message: "All elements have to be initialized");
    }

    if(p_Number < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            paramName: "p_Number", 
            message: "Parameter should be bigger then zero");

    var returnValue = new object();

    // do something where p_Parameter3 == null is allowed

    return returnValue;
}
```

Is it the right way to document those exceptions? Should I add one exception-tag for each case, or should I add only one for all Parameters for which null-values ar not allowed?

```xml
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
/// Thrown if p_Parameter1, p_Parameter2
/// or any element of p_Parameter2 are null</exception>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would definitely group the exceptions by type, ie `Thrown if p_Parameter1, p_Parameter2
or any element of p_Parameter2 are null`.

As a reference, look at the documentation at MSDN. An [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383356.aspx):

```
ArgumentNullException   |   Either path, contents, or encoding is null.
```

Comment: You're right, your example shows also that it's common to use "- or -" (UnauthorizedAccessException). In my opinion grouping could result in overlooking a certain reason for an exception. But if everybody is doing so, let's go with the tide ;)

Comment: The "- or -" grouping seems to be how the Microsoft docs render multiple `exception` tags. See e.g. [TrySetException(IEnumerable<Exception>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.trysetexception?view=netcore-2.1#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskCompletionSource_1_TrySetException_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Exception__) and the corresponding [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskCompletionSource.cs#L179)

Answer (score 2):

MSDN is a good source to emulate in this case, and taking a survey of a [few](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cb5zb8y.aspx) [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx) it looks like they tend to use one `exception` block and enumerate the different parameters inside of it.

Doing it this way makes it easier for consumers of your code to know what exceptions to possibly catch because seeing a list of distinct exceptions is easier to grok than a list that contains duplicates.